# iOS - Voice Over - Accessibility for large amounts

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

I am not able to make iOS voice over / Accessiblity read large amounts in money format for example £782284.00 , this should read as seven hundered eighty two thousand , two hundered and eight four, but iOS voice over reads this as seven eight two two eight four.

Comment: That is OK. VoiceOver users are used to this. If you try to override it you risk confusing them and breaking the experience.

Comment: VoiceOver on the Mac can change this setting.  Too bad it's not available in iOS too.  On the Mac, hit VO+V, then right arrow to the numbers setting and change it from 'digits' to 'words'.  You can also set it in the system preferences via the voiceover utility dialog.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to get your purpose is to [format perfectly your numbers](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/development/#date-time-and-numbers) to be vocalized as desired by VoiceOver.

Use of `NumberFormatter` and `.spellOut` style to read out the `accessibilityLabel` are [important tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55276007/3825084) to **adapt the VoiceOver vocalization for large amounts**.

I deeply encourage you to try and vocalize numbers as they should : the application content **MUST** be adapted to the VoiceOver users, not the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

It is really important to make sure you do all you can to make the app easier to use for VoiceOver users.  I have been running an app for sighted and visually impaired players, you can see an example of this method running in the inventory section of the app:
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/swordy-quest-an-rpg-adventure/id1446641513

The number of requests I got from blind & visually impaired players to read out millions as millions, rather than individual digits, was huge.  Please do take the extra effort to make it fully VoiceOver compatible.  It makes life so much easier for VoiceOver users.  Here is a method I created solely for this purpose, that VoiceOver seems to like.  You are basically adding thousand comma separators:

```
// e.g. 1000 -> "1,000"
public static func addCommaSeperatorsToInt(number: Int) -> String {
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
    return numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: number))!
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I agree to @aadrian is suggesting, try not to break convention VoiceOver users are used to. Because some large numbers are read in a long time, then the users have slow navigation across numbers.

However, if that is the case you need it hard, [here you can have](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213360/how-to-convert-a-numeric-value-into-english-words-in-excel) (I couldnot find sth for swift/objc but you will get the idea) a number to word converter and then you can set that to _.accessbilityLabel of the UIView or whatever. Then it will read as you like.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21774899/voice-over-doesnt-read-phone-number-properly)

Comment: if you look at android, it does have the capacity to read out millions,billions and  trillions. And i think thats the right way to do things, Unfortunately iOS still does not have this as a default feature. Sorry this is not a convention I feel this is a bug which needs to be improved by Apple.

Comment: May be. How does the audience think?

Comment: VoiceOver has the capacity to read out dates and numbers as they should like android does apparently as well. The only thing to remember is a perfect formatted element as an incoming parameter. See my answer to be convinced.